# Caffeine + Xscreensaver = Not Working

Tags: 11.10, screensaver

Had removed Gnome-screensaver and uses xscreensaver, but Caffeine doesn't seems to work when watching movie using SMPlayer even added both SMPlayer and MPlayer into the activation list.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug (an especially annoying one since 11.10 uses GNOME 3 which has no screensavers). Thankfully someone's working on fixing it:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/caffeine/+bug/878690

Comment: This now seems to be fixed in the newest version, available via the Caffeine PPA: https://launchpad.net/~caffeine-developers/+archive/ppa

Answer (score 0):

Marcar Iniciar Caffeine al inciar seción

Matar definitivamente el demonio de gnome-secreensave, dejamos sin permiso de ejecución

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver
```

Y reiniciamos la PC

**Translation (via Google translate):**

Take Caffeine out of startup (translation unclear here)

I would definitely kill the daemon `gnome-screensaver` and leave it without execute permission:

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver
```

Then reboot the PC.